# Open app after clicked from Channel in Android TV (Oreo)

Tags: android, android-tv

In this image :

[image]

I checked :

- Number 1 & Number 3 : It's **able to clicked and open**.

In number 3, they are Application,

I am also developing my own Application and can show it in number 3.

But **my App can not clicked and open**,

Please suggest me which attribute need define in where for me to **make my App can clicked and open app directly?**

Thank you,

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: You can follow this guides to Recommend content.
https://developer.android.com/training/tv/discovery/recommendations
https://developer.android.com/training/tv/discovery/recommendations-channel.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After do some research, I found [this Document](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/discovery/recommendations-channel) to do.

- Must use : `setAppLinkIntentUri()` method
- Reinstall app

As code in below

```
// NOTE : THESE INFO MUST MATCH WITH DATA IN MANIFEST.XML
    String SCHEME = "xxx";
    String HOST = "xxx";
    String PATH = "xxx";

    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, MainActivity.class.getName());
    String channelInputId = TvContractCompat.buildInputId(componentName);

    // Design Channel Data on Launcher in here
    Channel channel = new Channel.Builder()
            .setDisplayName(mContext.getString(R.string.mv_hot_title))
            .setType(TvContractCompat.Channels.TYPE_PREVIEW)
            .setInputId(channelInputId)
            .setAppLinkIntentUri(Uri.parse(SCHEME + "://" + HOST + "/" + PATH))
            .build();
```